# jsPDF overlapping dynamic

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to use user generated in a PDF.
I do not know how to prevent the next text from overlapping.

```
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true});

doc.text("long string that can be too long rorem ipsum", data.settings.margin.left + 15, 22, { { align: "right", maxWidth: 210 } });

doc.text("some more text", data.settings.margin.left + 15, 32);
```

I know how to make it work using autoTable, but not without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make it.

```
const pirnt = "long string that can be too long rorem ipsum"
doc.text(pirnt, data.settings.margin.left + 15, 22, { { align: "right", maxWidth: 210 } });
let long = doc.getTextWidth(pirnt);
let infit = (Math.ceil(long / 210) - 1);
```

This may not be the best solution, but does the job, barely.

Answer (score 0):

**This may help :**
doc.text("long string that can be too long rorem ipsum", data.settings.margin.left + 15, 22, { style:{ align: "right", maxWidth: 210 } });